# "Invalid URL" message on webpage while accessing marketing Cloudpage on live site

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, ssl, sender-authentication-package

We are receiving "Invalid URL" message on webpage while accessing one of the Salesforce Marketing-Cloud Cloudpage on a live website. Below are some details from our environment.

1. The cloudpage where we are encountering "Invalid Error" message is hosted on Marketing cloud's by default domain i.e. "pub.s6.exacttarget.com"
2. we had purchased SSL certificates and new domain(Pvt. domain) but the cloudpage was still on the default domain and the SSL certificate was not applied to that page

Does anyone know the exact reason we are encountering invalid URL message? Is there any issue if we use cloudpage without SSL certificate, the cloud page was working fine till last week.

Comment: Note to the second point - when you purchase SSL, your old unsecured pages are not automatically switched to HTTPS and it became possible to use a toggle to do in the CloudPage Properties only within recent releases.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess that this one got affected by the recent implementation of the **[tenant subdomain usage for non-custom domain Cloud Pages](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_rn_june_2021_cp_urls_support_tse.htm&type=5)**

Essentially meaning that the old stack specific (like you shared with the `pub.s6` domain) are no longer going to be functional and are instead replaced by tenant subdomain string, similar to what happened with the API and FTPs.  This was implemented June 2021, but there was a redirect available that was automatically moving it to the new domain. Across many different stacks and accounts now, this redirect has been turned off which is now giving that invalid url error.

> Although the new TSE-based URLs are live as of June 2021, the old CloudPage URLs still function via redirect. This redirect capability is a temporary service to allow impacted customers to change their old CloudPage URLs to the new TSE-based URLs.

Example change of URL:

> URL Change Examples:
>
> Old URLs = https://pub.exacttarget.com or https://[GUID].pub.sfmc-content.com
>
> New URL = https://[string].pub.sfmc-content.com

The new URL you need is located underneath the name in the Cloud Pages edit page window.

Comment: Thanks you for your response and explanation,  can you please let me know where we can find this string?https://[string].pub.sfmc-content.com.   also I observed that old url with pub.s7.exacttarget.com is redirecting to https://[string].pub.sfmc-content.com but that system is doing it automatically

Comment: Redirecting to https://[string].pub.sfmc-content.com but still giving an error invalid url